# Backup a LUKS encrypted device on the cloud

Tags: security, backup, encryption, luks

I am going to use **LUKS** for encryption, however I cannot find a thoughtful manual and best practices how to do so. Here I will list my questions, sorry for naivety.

1. Apparently I don't need to encrypt the entire disk, maybe I should place a `home` on a different partition and encrypt only this partition? Any advantages vs disadvantages?
2. How to backup the encrypted partition on the cloud? I found that I should backup the LUKS header too, should I place them in the different places?

Comment: Are you going to use a block-based backup to save the encrypted block layer to cloud, or the filesystem block layer above that, or are you expecting to use a file-based backup (such as `rsnapshot`/`rsync`)? Depending on which level you're backing up, you may not even see LUKS

Comment: The disclaimer is that once you back up LUKS header (or the whole drive containing the header) to the cloud, LUKS password change feature becomes less useful, as anybody with access to your old password, old header, and new image of the drive will be able to fully decrypt the new image (including the new files). Also with old header but without old password they can still try to brute force the old password if it didn't have enough entropy (was too short or too simple).

Answer (score 2):

> Apparently I don't need to encrypt the entire disk, maybe I should place a `home` on a different partition and encrypt only this partition? Any advantages vs disadvantages?

The advantage of encrypting the entire disk is you don't have to mentally reason about where files might end up on disk outside `/home`, for example in `/tmp` or `/var` or swap. Most schemes need to have `/boot` in the clear so Grub can do its thing though.

> How to backup the encrypted partition on the cloud? I found that I should backup the LUKS header too, should I place them in the different places?

Backing up the disk as blocks is inefficient because the high entropy arising from the encryption reduces the benefit of compression. Don't think about backing up "the disk", consider how you back up "the data" (i.e. files) and do it independently of how you're protecting them locally (e.g. a backup program that can make use of encryption itself, such as Duply and GnuPG).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But for me it still not clear, should I store LUKS partition header separately? And how to manage gpg keys?